# How to update my MySQL table column with unique random sequence number?

Tags: php, mysql

I try to update my MySQL table column, and set random sequence number, begin from 1,2,3,etc. For example, I have total 38 row, so i need update it with number 1-38 (can't duplicate).
i tried using:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE=FLOOR(RAND()*38)+1
```

but it gives me some duplicate number, i need every rows have different number.

Comment: How are you planning to assign 1-36 to 38 rows without duplicate ?

Comment: i'm sorry. i already revised my questions its 1-38

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
SET @r := 0;
UPDATE  table
SET     value = (@r := @r + 1)
ORDER BY
        RAND();
```

This will assign numbers 1 to 38 would be assigned randomly and uniquely.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d67c/1)

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly what you want, but if you are looking towards assigning unique ID starting from 1 to your table, architectally good solution would be making your 'id' column an auto incrementing unique number:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN_NAME INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

If you already have the column, you could previously remove it:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1 : Do a for loop and store all 38 numbers in an array.
- Step 2 : shuffle that array using shuffle function.http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php
- Step 3 : Do a Foreach loop for that shuffled array and update your column.

Just example code:

```
  for($i=1;$i<=38;$i++)
  {
     $arr[$i] = $i;
  }

  shuffle($arr);

  foreach($arr as $randarray)
  {
     //Your SQL query here UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE=$randarray like that
  }
```

Comment: i try this, but all rows are updated with one same value only, return 1 distinct value.

Comment: what is the sql query you used ?

Comment: $update= mysql_query("update table set value=$randarray")
             or die(mysql_error());

Comment: create another column from 1 to 38 first

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution only in MySQL you need something like this:

```
update test set id =  (select MAX(id)+1 from test)  WHERE <your_condition>
```

But you will get error:

```
You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause
```

So you have to do something like that to avoid this error:

```
    update test set 
    id =  ( 
     select maxPlus1 from 
      (
       select MAX(id)+1 as maxPlus1 
       from test
      ) 
      maxTable
     ) WHERE <your_condition>
```

Comment: The Update query add all records with same value because `MAX(id)` is calculated only once, not for each row...